# Можно ли в php-класс добавить статический метод извне?

Tags: php, ооп, классы

В стиле с++, а-ля:

```
class Foo{

    static function ololo(){
        return 1;
    }

}

function Foo::bar(){
   return self::ololo();
}
```

В документации не нашел. Пробовал запустить представленный код, не получилось.

Comment: Какую реальную цель вы преследуете?

Answer (score 1):

Стандартными средствами текущая версия PHP такого сделать не позволит. Вы можете *изменить* свойство класса, но не добавить новое динамически (не считая экспериментальный способ, предложенный [@TheDoctor](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/415379/176792)). Например, можно сделать следующее:

```
class A {
   public static $method;
}

A::$method = function() { 
    print 'статический метод'; 
};

call_user_func(A::$method);
// или
$caller = A::$method;
$caller();
```

Причина этому, вероятнее всего, кроется в различнии типа языка: C++ -- компилируемый, а PHP -- интерпретируемый, т.е. выполняющийся в runtime, что вряд ли может позволить менять статические переменные в процессе исполнения.

Answer (score 0):

Есть что-то похожее, [вот оно.](https://php.net/manual/ru/function.runkit-method-add.php)
Добавление методов извне в принципе не есть хорошо, а статический метод...

UPD:

Как вариант: Добавить методом `registerStaticMethod` (название придумал, не ищи в доках) функцию в некий скоуп класса.
Затем вызывать её как стат. метод, сработает встроенный метод `__callStatic`, в нем организуй поиск в скоупе и вызывай хранимую там функцию или же нет, если её нет.

Comment: Не, этой штукой можно только обычные методы добавлять. Статические свойства не получится.

Comment: @VisioN, Угу, это можно понять по моему сообщению - только обычный метод, не статический.  
Вообще - статические методы/свойства довольно редко бывают полезными, хотя всё же бывают.

Answer (score 0):

Сложно себе представить ситуацию, когда такое может понадобится. Если можете - опишите ваши цели. Возможно ваша проблема немного по иному разрешится благодаря __callStatic.

Например, при реализации ActiveRecord так и делают. Статические методы "findByUsername", "findByLogin" и т.д. не описаны в классе, а реализованы за счет __callStatic. На основе имени вызываемого метода происходит выполнение того, что вам нужно.

Поэтому если и ваша ситуация позволяет решить проблему таким образом, то можете над этим задуматься. Если же вам необходимо добавлять абсолютно не похожие между собой методы, то тут уже как-то по другому нужно выкручиваться.

Comment: Это должен быть комментарий.

Comment: Не хватает репутации еще.

Comment: Тогда желательно расширить комментарий до полноценного ответа, например, приведя пример с кодом или более подробным объяснением.